# Copy a list to another list without losing the runtime type of original list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, copy, clone

I want to copy a `List<T>` to another list without losing the runtime type. All of the techniques that come to my mind is not achieving this.
(Also, I don't want to simply return the reference of the `input` list as I don't want edits in `input` list to be reflected into the copied list)

What I tried (see all the `copy*` methods) is listed below. As expected, none of them is giving `(x.getClass() == y.getClass())` to be `true`

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> x = new LinkedList<>();
        x.add(1);
        x.add(2);
        x.add(3);

        List<Integer> y = copy2(x);
        System.out.println("is runtime type equal? " + (x.getClass() == y.getClass()));
        // I want (x.getClass() == y.getClass()) to be true
        
        y.add(4);
        System.out.println(x); // should be [1, 2, 3]
        System.out.println(y); // should be [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }

    private static <T> List<T> copy0(List<T> input) {
        return new ArrayList<>(input);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> List<T> copy1(List<T> input) {
        Object[] x = input.toArray();
        return (List<T>) List.of(x);
    }

    private static <T> List<T> copy2(List<T> input) {
        return input.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static <T> List<T> copy3(List<T> input) {
        // Since Java 10
        return List.copyOf(input);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to make the caller send in a function that will create a new list of the same type. The alternative would be to use reflection, which would begin a stream of dangerous assumptions.

The following two are examples of *copy* implementations adapted from your code:

```
private static <T> List<T> copy0(List<T> input, Supplier<List<T>> newListCreator) {
    List<T> newList = newListCreator.get();
    newList.addAll(input);

    return newList;
}

private static <T> List<T> copy2(List<T> input, Supplier<List<T>> newListCreator) {
    return input.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(newListCreator));
}
```

And you can call either in this way:

```
List<Integer> y = copy2(x, LinkedList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LinkedList` is not an `ArrayList`. If you want both types to be equal, then  you might use reflection to invoke the default constructor of the actual class called in. Something like,

```
private static <T> List<T> copy0(List<T> input) {
    Class<?> cls = input.getClass();
    try {
        List<T> al = (List<T>) cls.getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
        Iterator<T> iter = input.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            al.add(iter.next());
        }
        return al;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which outputs

```
is runtime type equal? true
```

when I test it with your code. Note this makes dangerous assumptions about constructors and is not the approach I would take in a real project.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, the code shows below ignore `try... catch..`.

```
private static <T> List<T> copy2(List<T> input) { 
    List<T> instance = input.getClass().newInstance();
    return input.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> instance));
}
```